# WebScraping in Powershell with login section

Tags: powershell

I am trying to 
1. Login to my webapp
2. Check for some new rows in a table tag

I have issues with the step 1.

```
$username = "admin" 
$password = "admin" 
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible = $false
$ie.navigate("https://somesite.com") 
while ($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) { start-sleep -m 100 } 
#start-sleep 10
$ie.document.getElementById("login-form-username").value = "$username" 
$ie.document.getElementById("login-form-password").value = "$password" 
$ie.document.getElementById("login").submit()
start-sleep 20 
$ie.Document.body | Out-File -FilePath c:\web.txt
```

It opens IE11 and goes to the page.
But when it comes to need to findById and input - there is an error:
`The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set`
my HTML input section is:

```
<input name="os_username" class="text medium-field" id="login-form-username" type="text">
```

Comment: can u post the url?

Comment: @EylM sorry I cant. It is a local url on my local server in a company.

Comment: Its hard to test it.  is the element inside iframe? is it loaded dynamically by the javascript or it's part of the html source?

Comment: Could it be that there is another element with `id="login-form-username"` in your page?

Comment: here is the whole html: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/P37xvdc7gS/

Comment: Have you checked the HTML you posted? There is no element with `id="login-form-username"` in this document.

Comment: @cloned Thanks for the info. Funny thing..in my DOM Explorer (F12 in IE11) I can see the id. here is the image: https://i.imgur.com/EqBzOEI.png but when I click view source, it renders differently! How that can be possible?

Comment: here it is in source code: https://i.imgur.com/4bShRwI.png

Comment: if you double check the source code (image and/or code you posted) you will see that it's not an element with this id but rather an attribute for an element `<dashboard>` meaning this is most probably getting rendered via JS. maybe you need to fire some JS first to get the acutal rendering of the element.

Comment: @cloned and how to fire an js from powershell? is it doable?